# Não consigo remover um item copiado de uma lista para outra (drag e drop)

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, drag-n-drop, sortable, telerik

Tenho o seguinte código http://jsfiddle.net/6hLsfqtn/.

O meu problema ocorre da seguinte forma:

1. Adiciono um Estepe Duplo na lista da direita.
2. Adiciono um Estepe Simples na lista da direita.
3. Adiciono um segundo Estepe Duplo na lista da direita.
4. Arrasto um Estepe Duplo para o "Remover"
5. Os dois Estepes Duplos são removidos.

Eu já identifiquei que o problema está na remoção, pois mando remover o dataitem. Tentei passar dataitem.id e mesmo assim não funcionou pois os Id's se clonam ao arrastar alguma peça da lista da esquerda para direita.

Preciso que os Id's sejam diferentes para que ao remover com dataitem.id ele só remova uma peça.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que quando você adiciona os itens ao div da esquerda o UID (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#fields-uid) do objeto é o mesmo. Me refiro ao código:

```
dataItem = listA_DS.getByUid(draggableElement.data("uid"));
```

Não encontrei na documentação um metodo para criar um item novo a partir de outro. Então criei na mão mesmo. com o código:

```
dataItem = listA_DS.getByUid(draggableElement.data("uid"));
var novo = { id: dataItem.id, item: dataItem.item, img: dataItem.img };
listB_DS.add(novo);
```

Assim ele cria um uid novo a cada inserção e na hora de remover acaba o problema de remover todos.

Código disponível em http://jsfiddle.net/mapquintal/42js9axv/2/

Correções solicitadas por você em http://jsfiddle.net/mapquintal/42js9axv/3/

Comment: Perfeito! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava! Obrigada!

Comment: Marco é possível eu bloquear para ele não conseguir arrastar da lista da direita para ela mesma?

Comment: mas respondi essa tambem em http://jsfiddle.net/mapquintal/42js9axv/3/

Comment: Ah sim, obrigada